How to calculate the number of labelled trees with 6 vertices, at least 3 leaves, and a specific vertex as a leaf?
I'm working on a combinatorial problem from a past exam involving labelled trees. Specifically, I need to calculate the number of trees on the vertex set
$=\{\,1,2,3,4,5,6\,\}$ such that:

The tree has at least $3$ leaves.
Vertex $1$ is one of the leaves.

the correct answer is apparently $505$ trees, but I’m not sure how this number is derived. Could someone explain the steps to calculate this correctly? Any insights into how to approach this using combinatorial techniques would be appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

There are multiple different ways to count such tree, including careful consideration of all $1296$ labeled trees on $6$ vertices one by one. However I like the following solution.
One of proofs of Cayley's formula is based on Prüfer sequence. The idea is to iteratively delete in the remaining tree a leaf with minimum label and write down label of its neighbor while there are at least $3$ vertices in the tree. It can be proven that every possible sequence of $n - 2$ numbers from $[n] = \{\,1, 2, \ldots, n\,\}$ corresponds to exactly one labeled tree. Therefore there are $n^{n - 2}$ labeled treed on $n$ vertices.
However as soon as vertex $1$ should always be a leaf, it can't appear in the sequence. So the number of such labeled trees on $6$ vertices is $5^4 = 625$. Another condition is about at least $3$ leaves can be satisfied if we remove all trees with at most $2$ leaves. Since every tree has at least two leaves, we need to remove trees with exactly two leaves only. Every such tree is a path. And one of its ends is $1$. There are $5! = 120$ such labeled paths. So the answer is $5^4 - 5! = 505$.
